# IE10 throws SCRIPT1002: Syntax error inside conditional

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10

```js
;(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define([], factory);
  } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory();
  } else {
    root.MyClass = factory();
  }
}(this, function() {
  'use strict';

  if (/*@cc_on!@*/false && document.documentMode === 10) return;

  class MyClass {
    // ...
  }
}));
```

Classes obviously don't work in IE10. However, the conditional I'm using - `(/*@cc_on!@*/false && document.documentMode === 10)` - is there to disable it for IE10 (it works in every other case on the site). I've tried moving the conditional around to other places, wrapping the entire file in this conditional, etc, but with the same result.

Why does it still throw this error? And how can I get around it, so that this entire thing is ignored by IE10?

Comment: It's not clear from what you posted, but you have to think about what the code looks like if the `/*@cc_on!@*/` test succeeds; in other words, what the statement looks like to IE10. You've got it *inside* the `if` test, so that seems suspicious.

Comment: Also, the complete syntax of a code block must be understandable by the parser whether or not it ever executes.

Comment: Right, even if IE10 never actually enters the `if` block, it still needs to be able to parse it.  `if (false) { /* gotta parse this */ }` will fail if the comment is replaced with syntactically-invalid garbage code.

Comment: Ah yes, that of course makes sense. I keep thinking that parsers only run blocks _until_ they meet a conditional where they're supposed to exit. Do you have any suggestions on how to get around this issue?

Comment: Under normal circumstances I would say put the code that IE10 can't understand in its own file, and only include that file if you aren't in IE10.  But this is inside a module of some kind, and I don't know how to adapt that idea to this circumstance.

Comment: Or use a transpiler like Babel to compile your code into something that IE10 will be happy with.  Then you can use ES6, but compiled down into something IE can use.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that too, but I'm constrained in a CMS where I can't conditionally include files that way. Also, the module doesn't work after running through Babel, so I'm in quite a pickle here.

Comment: If your goal is to identify IE 10 browser then you can refer the example in this link. You can use that code instead of your above code may help to fix the error. Ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-the-user-is-using-internet-explorer-in-javascript/